# Bloch's theorem in one dimension, confusion about proof

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, unbounded-operators

I was looking at the derivation of Bloch's theorem in Griffith's QM:
If $V(x+a)=V(x)$ for any $x$ and some $a$, and
$\psi$ solves
$$
H\psi =\lambda \psi
$$
for $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\pi}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$
then
$$
\psi(x+a)=e^{ika}\psi(x)
$$

The proof relies on the fact that since the shift operator $D\psi(x)=\psi(x+a)$ commutes with the Hamiltonian, we may take an eigenfunction of $H$ to serve as an eigenfunction for $D$. The wikipedia article on the theorem (on a 3 dimensional crystal lattice but the principle is the same) once again asserts the existence of a simultaneous eigenbasis for the two operators.

What am I missing here? I know that this is a fact for matrices, but we are working over $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ here, where I don't believe this is true for unbounded self adjoint operators, and it is not clear to me why it should be true with this particular operator (indeed I think it is not).

Thanks for any help and I apologize if I am being naive.

Comment: I think Griffiths is not the place you should be if you are even asking these questions. Try Brian Hall's Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians, or Barry Simon's Methods of Mathematical Physics.

Comment: Fair enough. I am also reading through the first Volume of the Simon series and couldn't find a reference to the theorem; do you know if it is in a later volume? Thank you for the other reference as well. @user14717

Comment: You can show that $D$ commutes with the Laplacian, and by virtue of $V(x) = V(x+a)$ you can then show that both $H$ and $D$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris diagonalizable? My point is that we are not in the finite dimensional setting.

Comment: @qbert that's fine, the spectral theorem still applies on compact operators in general Hilbert spaces, so we can talk about unitary diagonalization in the same way as we can for finite cases (of course, being far more careful about what things satisfy these conditions, which is something Griffiths is unconcerned with).

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris The hamiltonian is not compact, it's not even bounded! And yes there is a spectral theorem for unbounded self adjoint operators as well, but I don't see how it addresses my concern

Comment: @qbert Sorry, yes, you're correct. I should be more careful, the spectral theorem still holds in an (only slightly weaker form) if we have *closedness* of the operator. See Akhiezer's *Theory of Linear Operators*, if I recall correctly. My point was in noting that simultaneous diagonalizability is a well-defined concept that makes sense when showing that both operators commute.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris Yes, there is a well defined notion of simultaneous diagonalizability, and I will concede that this is enough to take the theorem as morally true. But even knowing the spectral theorem for unbounded self adjoint operators, I do not see the proof.

Comment: @qbert: just found a nice paper which roughly addresses the problems which you are concerned about, but in a much more complicated setting: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-070-02/S0002-9947-1951-0041010-X/S0002-9947-1951-0041010-X.pdf, Tosio Kato, Fundamental Properties of Hamiltonian Operators of Schrodinger Type.

Comment: The point being that it took 25-some years from writing down the Schrodinger equation to proving it was self-adjoint in cases of practical relevance. The question is a difficult one.

Comment: @user14717 thank you very much. I also found a relevant source in Barry Simon's "Szego's theorem and its descendants" if one is willing to use the discrete Schrodinger operator as a heuristic. The relevant portion is chapter 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement, if considered for a Hamiltonian with periodic potential which acts as a densely defined selfadjoint operator on an L^2 of the full space R^n, is wrong. Therefore, you won't find "Bloch's theorem" in this form in Reed/Simon. 
In vol 4., Reed and Simon treat Schroedinger operators with periodic potentials in chapter XIII.16.

You find there a theorem saying that under reasonable assumptions about the regularity of the periodic potential, the Hamiltonian operator has purely absolutely continuous spectrum (which gives rise to the physicist's "band structure") and therefore no eigenvalues or eigenfunctions would exist as elements in the Hilbert space. (Theorem XII.90 for 1 dimension and Theorem XIII.100 for dimensions at least 2.)

Physicists switch repeatedly between a treatment of finitely many stacked/translated primitive cells and the case of the full space with infinitely many translations of a primitive cell. Reed and Simon comment on this situation when they explain the "density of states measure" near the end of this chapter in Theorem XIII.101.
Finitely many cells give an L^2-space over a compact domain. In this case, the Hamiltonian usually will have compact resolvents and a complete orthonormal set of eigenstates. There will be no continuous "band structure", but only discrete spectrum.
In the case of the full space, the direct integral decomposition of Reed/Simon explains how the continuous band-structure is obtained from combining the discrete spectra of operators of a family H(q) (in the "p-space version") or H(theta) (in the "x-space version"). 
A sort of "eigenfunction expansion" is provided in Thereom XIII.98 (b).

As for Floquet's theorem for ODEs (i.e. one space dimension, no L^2-space...) you can find a nice explanation of the monodromy matrix and of the charateristic exponents in  Vladimir Arnol'd's book about ordinary differential equations, and a "modern" proof in Hale's or Amann's or Walter's book about ordinary differential equations.

Comment: This is a really great answer. I will read what you suggest as soon as I can get back to the library. A question about the finite number of cells version: it seems like here the argument above could potentially be salvaged except that the shift operator wont be compact. Any ideas on this?

Comment: In 1 dimension in the infinitely extended case, you will have eg. a closed interval [-1/2,1/2] as a primitive cell and a 1-periodic potential V (smooth, say). The finitely stacked situation consists of a finite number (say N) of such intervals arranged in a chain to give [-N/2,N/2]. Physicists start with such a finite chain and take the Hilbert space $L^2[-N/2, N/2]$. The kinetic energy operator is taking (-1) times a second derivative, you have to provide boundary conditions to obtain a selfadjoint operator. Then implement the shift translations (not faithful) and find common eigenfunctions.

Comment: Got it. I was overthinking the shift operator. Thanks again

Comment: Now, that you got it, go for Reed/Simon vol. 4 and try to understand, how physicists' Bloch functions appear in connection with the direct integral decompositions. Unfortunately, Reed/Simon did not comment explicitely on this relation, so one has to do this last step oneself.